# Using Eclipse File Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

How do i do a Netbeans style ***Select In Project*** in  Eclipse/Aptana?

Also most editors when we click ***File > Open***  opens the explorer in the directory of the current file(file that I am working on) but that's not the case with Eclipse/Aptana. How do i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i do a Netbeans style Select In Project in Eclipse/Aptana?

In eclipse , you can use **Navigate --> Show In**  , or use its default hot key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and choose a view that you want the current editing file to be selected in .